# Evaluation of Sympy expression doesn't yield correct result

Tags: python, sympy

Why is the difference between `fdeno` and `deno2` so big in the following code?

```py
from sympy import symbols

sign2 = symbols('sign2')

deno = sign2*(sign2 - 1.6)*(sign2 - 1.5)*(sign2 - 1.4)*(sign2 - 1.3)*(sign2 - 1.2)*(sign2 - 1.1)*(sign2 - 1.0)*(sign2 - 0.9)*(sign2 - 0.8)*(sign2 - 0.7)*(sign2 - 0.6)*(sign2 - 0.5)*(sign2 - 0.4)*(sign2 - 0.3)*(sign2 - 0.2) 

"""not include the term (sign2 -0.1)"""

fdeno = float(deno.evalf(subs={sign2:round(0.1,1)},n=15))

deno2 = 0.1*(0.1-1.6)*(0.1-1.5)*(0.1-1.4)*(0.1 - 1.3)*(0.1 - 1.2)*(0.1 - 1.1)*(0.1 - 1.0)*(0.1 - 0.9)*(0.1 - 0.8)*(0.1 - 0.7)*(0.1 - 0.6)*(0.1 - 0.5)*(0.1 - 0.4)*(0.1 - 0.3)*(0.1 - 0.2) 

print(fdeno,"//",deno2)

# Output:
0.0 // -0.00013076743679999998
```

Comment: It works when you specify `n=63` (or greater) but I can't say why this is the case.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are running out of precision for your float.

To solve, define sign2 as a 0.1 with 30 decimal positions:

```
fdeno = float(deno.evalf(subs={sign2: Float('0.1', 30)}))
```